# Configure composite filter for specific logger in Log4j2 via properties file

Tags: log4j2

Log4j2 provides various kind of filters [1] and these can be configured at four levels:

1. Context-wide
2. Logger
3. Appender
4. Appender Reference

In my use-case, I would like to setup a `CompositeFilter` at a **specified Logger** (level 2 from above) using the **property file syntax**.

For the sake of the example let's assume that we want to setup a composite filter composed from two `RegexFilter` matching `.*SQL.*` and `.*JPQL.*` respectively. Assuming that we have the following events:

```
logger.info("Messase with no keyword");
logger.info("Messase with SQL keyword");
logger.info("Messase with JPQL keyword");
logger.info("Messase with both SQL and JPQL keywords");
```

Only the last event should pass from the composite filter.

I made several attempts [2] (also outlined below) to get the desired output but I wasn't able to figure out how to properly setup a `CompositeFilter` using the property syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Attempt 0**

```
logger.t1.filter.f1.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.f1.regex = .*SQL.*
logger.t1.filter.f1.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filter.f1.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.filter.f2.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.f2.regex = .*JPQL.*
logger.t1.filter.f2.onMatch = ACCEPT
logger.t1.filter.f2.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.appenderRefs = a
logger.t1.appenderRef.a.ref = L0
```

**Attempt 1**

```
logger.t1.filters = f1, f2
logger.t1.filter.f1.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.f1.regex = .*SQL.*
logger.t1.filter.f1.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filter.f1.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.filter.f2.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.f2.regex = .*JPQL.*
logger.t1.filter.f2.onMatch = ACCEPT
logger.t1.filter.f2.onMismatch = DENY
```

**Attempt 2**

```
logger.t1.filters.f1.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filters.f1.regex = .*SQL.*
logger.t1.filters.f1.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filters.f1.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.filters.f2.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filters.f2.regex = .*JPQL.*
logger.t1.filters.f2.onMatch = ACCEPT
logger.t1.filters.f2.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.appenderRefs = a
logger.t1.appenderRef.a.ref = L0
```

**Attempt 3**

```
logger.t1.filter.M.type = Filters
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.regex = .*SQL.*
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.regex = .*JPQL.*
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.onMatch = ACCEPT
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.appenderRefs = a
logger.t1.appenderRef.a.ref = L0
```

Some further clarifications:

- I am strictly interested for setting up a `CompositeFilter`, not
  write a custom filter, not use a single combined `RegexFilter` etc.
- I am interested to see how it is done using the property syntax, not
  XML, JSON, or other.

[1] https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html

[2] https://github.com/zabetak/logging-log4j2/commit/a9944885100db42f7e3ba1b3ff81d59b743d0ab7

Comment: You should include the configuration as text in the question for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Piotr! I updated the question with the various attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your configuration:

1. A `LoggerConfig` accepts only a single filter. If you want to use multiple filters, configure a `CompositeFilter` explicitly (which has a plugin name "Filters),
2. The order of filters in a properties configuration file is basically random, since `Properties` is a `Hashtable` and does not have a predefined order.

Considering the two facts above a variation of your attempt 3 should work:

```
logger.t1.filter.M.type = Filters
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.regex = .*SQL.*
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filter.M.f1.onMismatch = DENY
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.type = RegexFilter
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.regex = .*JPQL.*
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.onMatch = NEUTRAL
logger.t1.filter.M.f2.onMismatch = DENY
```

Both filters return `NEUTRAL`, when the pattern matches, which guarantees that an inversion of the order of filters does not break the logic.

Comment: I was afraid that attempt 3 was not the right way to proceed forward since I am getting the following error: `ERROR StatusLogger Filters contains invalid attributes "onMatch", "onMismatch"`. Is this normal?

Comment: @zabetak: it isn't, but there is already issue [LOG4J2-3453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3453) for that. Ironically it is a logging problem: that message should not be logged.